# $f:S^1\to S^1 $ is homotopic to constant map then there exist z such that $f(z)=f(-z)$

Tags: real-analysis

> $f:S^1\to S^1 $ is homotopic to constant map then there exist z such that $f(z)=f(-z)$

I can prove result for $f:S^n\to R^n $ using Borsuk Ulam Theorem without using any condition of homotopic to constant.I do not know how to start the solution.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the usual covering map $\pi:\Bbb R\to S^1$. As $f$ is homotopic to a
constant map,
it can be lifted to $\Bbb R$, that is $f=\pi\circ g$ where $g:S^1\to\Bbb R$ is continuous. Now apply Borsuk-Ulam to $g$.